# Models field request returns null

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I've just added a new field called 'locale' to the users table and I am trying to get its walue with auth()->user()->locale. But I am getting null. When I dd() auth()->user(), I can clearly see locale with its value. Also this filed is mass assignable.
Mass assignment is actually active, I mean locale field is in $fillable array. Btw you can see that on the screenshot below.

Calling

`dd(auth()->user())`

http://prntscr.com/kilhb0

Comment: Do you get the same when you use Auth::user()->locale ?

Comment: `Auth::` and `auth()` are equivalent, it's a `Facade` vs a helper.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any methods on your model named `locale()`, such as accessors, relationships, etc. They will take precedence over the property.

Comment: It extends base Model class, you mean that it contains suck a method?

Comment: Can you post your `User` model? There might be a `public function locale()` on it, that's being accessed (via `->locale`, without the `()`) instead of your `locale` attribute (from table column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. As @aken-roberts said the problem was in naming. As I see field name `locale` is reserved, so somehow this field was always returning null.